# a switch jumping in unexpected place

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, switch-statement, case

I have forked a C++ project and added some cases in a switch. Then it jumps in the middle of the next case. The condition is an `int`, the case values are `#define`d. As the code is big, I write here something equivalent and simple:

```
#define AAA 1
#define BBB 2
int X::func(int i) {
  bool b = (i == 5);
  int v = (b ? 10 : 5);
  switch (i) {
    case AAA:
      if (b && v > 4) {
        v = v + 1;
        return 0;
      }
      break;
    case BBB:
      if (!b || v > 40) {
        v = v + 2;
        b = false; // direct jump here from the switch for i = AAA
        return 0;
      }
      break;
  }
return -1;
}
```

If I pass AAA to X::func, the code execution jumps directly from the `switch` to `b = false;` inside the BBB case. In the real code, I have tens of cases, and it happens in the middle. If I comment entierely `case BBB`, it jumps at the same place in the comments ! Every case ends with a `break;` and has no variable declaration inside. Like here the variables b and v, they are declared before the switch statement.

Part of the cases are in a `#ifdef` `#endif` block. The additional cases where the problem occur are in this block. The condition is true, so the block is compiled. Anyway, I have tested it after having suppressed these two precompiler statements, and it is the same.

If I add brackets `{}` to fully embrasse the cases like here, I still have the same result:

```
case BBB: {
  if (!b || v > 40) {
    v = v + 2;
    b = false; // direct jump here from the switch for i = AAA
    return 0;
  }
  break;
}
```

Everything compiles fine and executes the same, either in a debug session or in normal execution. I use gcc 4.5.4 under Eclipse CDT Indigo.

It looks like a compiler bug, but what could be the cause ?

Comment: Does this "equivalent" code have the same problem?

Comment: Are you by any chance debugging with optimizations turned on?

Comment: The fact that it jumps to the same place in the comments tells me that you are not actually debugging your "latest build".  Note that optimized release code can jump around like crazy without any method to their madness (yeah, I know that's not really true, but you compiler writers have some pretty intersting ideas like inter-module optimization <pop stack>).  Rarely, rarely, are there compiler bugs anymore - that's not to say they're not, but 999 out of 1000, the "compiler buggy" code is actually doing exactly what you told it to do (I'm amazed how it does that!)   :-D

Comment: Make your cases and conditions simpler. Your "equivalent" code looks like a mess. If _"Part of the cases are in a #ifdef #endif block."_, this only makes things worse.

Comment: Pending a response to doctorlove's comment... If the "equivalent" code doesn't have the same problem, it doesn't help much. There could be some factor you're not seeing that doesn't exist in the derived code (actually this is the most probable scenario). Without seeing this factor, we cannot know what's wrong. Any code provided absolutely should reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did a clean and complete rebuild. It is the same. My compile options are dubugger turned on :  CFLAGS="-g -O0" CPPFLAGS=-DDEBUG CXXFLAGS="-g -O0"

gcc -march=native -msse4 -mcx16 -msahf -O0 -pipe -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -fPIE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -Winit-self -Wwrite-strings -Wdiv-by-zero -std=gnu99

Comment: Turn optimisations off. Comment out case BBB. If it steps into the comments, then... well. Report back.

Comment: In the real code, optimisations are already off. I have just recheck the autotools variables, the compiler options (both gcc and g++). If I comment case B, it jumps in the comments, yes. I am going to test my "equivalent code" with the same settings.....

Comment: @lalebarde: To check code execution order, print some debug information to stderr (or stdout). And stop worrying about code execution order in debugger. Also see my answer.

Comment: @SigTerm: If I cannot use the debugger, it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have build a "cloned" project (project_test) from the original one (project). In the pre-build steps, I have a rsync that copies all source files (the point is to not copy the autotools stuff):

```
rsync -a --exclude=tests/* --exclude=perf/* --exclude=tools/*  --include=*/ --include=*.[ch] --include=*.[ch]pp --exclude=* ${workspace_loc:/project}/ ${workspace_loc:/project_test}/ && cp ${workspace_loc:/project}/tests/one_with_main.cpp ${workspace_loc:/project_test}/tests/
```

It builds well, and the debugging is as expected.

An alternative could be `rsync -a --delete` instead of `rsync -a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stepping through the function via debugger then "currently highlighted line" in debugger does not necessarily correspond to the line currently being executed (when loops are involved, when optimizations are turned on, when there's lots of macros, etc).

print the variables to the stdout/stderr after the switch and see if their values are correct. Also print some debug lines to stdout/stderr within both `cases`. If output you get is correct, stop worrying about strange code execution order.

Example:

```
#define AAA 1
#define BBB 2
int X::func(int i) {
  bool b = (i == 5);
  int v = (b ? 10 : 5);
  std::cout << "before switch/case" << std::endl;
  switch (i) {
    case AAA:
      std::cout << "AAA, before if block" << std::endl;
      if (b && v > 4) {
        v = v + 1;
        std::cout << "within AAA if block" << std::endl;
        return 0;
      }
      std::cout << "AAA, after if block" << std::endl;
      break;
    case BBB:
      std::cout << "BBB, before if block" << std::endl;
      if (!b || v > 40) {
        v = v + 2;
        b = false; // direct jump here from the switch for i = AAA
        std::cout << "BBB, within if block" << std::endl;
        return 0;
      }
      std::cout << "BBB, after if block" << std::endl;
      break;
  }
  std::cout << "after switch/case" << std::endl;
  return -1;
}
```

--edit--

It might help if you add {} brackets for case statements:

```
case AAA:{
    break;
}
```

And it will definitely help if you move stuff from cases into separate functions. This won't improve the code, but debugger will definitely be able to walk through them.

Comment: This is a semi-reasonable workaround, but not a solution. The fact that the debugger is screwing up on this suggests that either OP is not compiling with whatever flags he thinks he is compiling with, or he is not debugging the latest build. Both of those potential issues could cause him a lot of grief which your debug statements won't solve. Also, using debug statements is a very primitive and restricted form of debugging and it's much better to have full debugger working in the general case.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: IMO, it is a common thing that debugger screws up on flow control (even on debug build), and you might not be able to fix it. I gave up getting correct behavior from Q_FOREACH long time ago.

Comment: When I change the printf somewhat, the output changes. So I conclude I am debugging what I expect to debug. The printf are good. But the debugger is unusable as this. Can it be due to autotools ? I will try to set-up a shadow project with classic builds with pre-copy of the sources.

Comment: @lalebarde: It could be because you aren't generating enough debug info, or because you're actually optimizing the code when you think that all optimizations are disabled, and so on. Instead of autotools I'd recommend either CMake or qmake (qmake is a part of qt). Those tools are easier to deal with. IMO, unless you absolutely have to use autotools, you should probably avoid it.

Comment: CFLAGS = -g3 -O0
CPP = gcc -std=gnu99 -E
CPPFLAGS = -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g3 -O0 -DZMQ_FORCE_EPOLL
CXX = g++
CXXCPP = g++ -E
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CXXFLAGS = -g3 -O0
My Makefile flags looks right. So I give up with autotools. What I am trying now is to build a kind of mirror project with only the source files that are rsync from the original project, and let Eclipse CDT defaults building tools work.